# How to pass generic List<User> to restful web services

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have the requirement to create the search operation using restful web services, i.e, using @GET. The method signature takes String and List as input argument and returns List.

```
public Generic List <Employer> getAllEmployer(String employeeName, Generic List <employeeLocation>);
```

Kindly request if someone could describe on how to implement the same. Should I use query param or path param or form param. I need to return the List of employer in json format.

Answer (score -1):

if the employee locations  are just string, pass them as comma seperated values and spring will take care of converting it to list. I would rather suggest just to have it as a pathparam rather than having it as a query param.

Comment: Hi, employee location class contains more metadata (deparment, salary, lcoation, designation) which is also required for creating the search operation and increasing the response time of the query. So employee location needs to be passed as List<EmployeeLocation>

Answer (score -1):

This is just my opinion but I think that the "RESTful" way to pass multiple parameters with the same name would be to a MultiValueMap.

Spring and Jersey both have implementations of MultiValueMap however, below is an example of a spring implementation:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/employer/_search"})
public List<Employer> search(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> params) {
    return someService.search(params);
}
```

They way that you would call this url would then become:

```
/employer/_search?employeeName=name&location=1&location=2&location=3
```

Then behind the scenes spring will create the MultiValueMap for you which is a `Map<String,List<String>>` where any parameters with the same name are put into the same list.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for the suggestion. However I am not using spring framework on the project. Its purely web service application dedicated for Java rest web services implementing through jersey. If you could show me the code snippet of how to implement the same without spring framework.

Comment: I believe that jersey also has an implementation of MultivaluedMap I am not sure on the exact implementation as I have never used jersey before.

Comment: If MultiValueMap is working for me then I would be good to go, else would need to research. Thanks a lot Eric for your suggestion. Cheers